# Creating a copy constructor of a triangle resulting in copy of null error

Tags: java, encapsulation

I'm in an intermediate java class and we have a project that is essentially creating code that checks whether the given values of a triangle creates a proper triangle (positive side lengths and nonzero area) using encapsulation. We were also given a class full of tests to make sure that our code works correctly. I've got most of the code done but a few of the methods aren't passing the tests that they're supposed to and I'm not sure how to fix this.

This is the description of the method: "Triangle(Triangle triangle): Initialize a new Triangle by assigning each instance variable of the given Triangle to the corresponding variable of the new Triangle. (This is known as a "copy constructor.") If the reference given to the method is null, assign DEFAULT_SIDE to each variable instead."

This is the method that I wrote:

```
public Triangle(Triangle triangle)
{
    Triangle newTriangle = new Triangle();
    
    if (triangle != null)
    {
        if (isTriangle(triangle.getSideA(), triangle.getSideB(), triangle.getSideC()))
        {
            newTriangle.setSideA(triangle.getSideA());
            newTriangle.setSideB(triangle.getSideB());
            newTriangle.setSideC(triangle.getSideC());
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        newTriangle.setSideA(DEFAULT_SIDE);
        newTriangle.setSideB(DEFAULT_SIDE);
        newTriangle.setSideC(DEFAULT_SIDE); 
    }
}
```

and this is the code that tests it:

```
@Test
void testCopyConstructor() {
    // Test invalid input.
    Triangle triangle = null;
    Triangle copy = new Triangle(triangle);
    double[] expected = {1, 1, 1};
    String msg = "Copy of null";
    checkSides(copy, expected, msg);
    
    for (int idx = 0; idx < SIDES.length; ++idx) {
        double a = SIDES[idx][0];
        double b = SIDES[idx][1];
        double c = SIDES[idx][2];
        double expectedA = 1;
        double expectedB = 1;
        double expectedC = 1;
        if (IS_TRIANGLE[idx]) {
            expectedA = a;
            expectedB = b;
            expectedC = c;
        }
        String format = "Copy of Triangle(%.4f, %.4f, %.4f)";
        
        // Test each permutation of the sides.
        triangle = new Triangle(a, b, c);
        copy = new Triangle(triangle);
        expected = new double[] {expectedA, expectedB, expectedC};
        msg = String.format(format, a, b, c);
        checkSides(copy, expected, msg);
        
        triangle = new Triangle(a, c, b);
        copy = new Triangle(triangle);
        expected = new double[] {expectedA, expectedC, expectedB};
        msg = String.format(format, a, c, b);
        checkSides(copy, expected, msg);
        
        triangle = new Triangle(b, a, c);
        copy = new Triangle(triangle);
        expected = new double[] {expectedB, expectedA, expectedC};
        msg = String.format(format, b, a, c);
        checkSides(copy, expected, msg);
        
        triangle = new Triangle(b, c, a);
        copy = new Triangle(triangle);
        expected = new double[] {expectedB, expectedC, expectedA};
        msg = String.format(format, b, c, a);
        checkSides(copy, expected, msg);
        
        triangle = new Triangle(c, a, b);
        copy = new Triangle(triangle);
        expected = new double[] {expectedC, expectedA, expectedB};
        msg = String.format(format, c, a, b);
        checkSides(copy, expected, msg);
        
        triangle = new Triangle(c, b, a);
        copy = new Triangle(triangle);
        expected = new double[] {expectedC, expectedB, expectedA};
        msg = String.format(format, c, b, a);
        checkSides(copy, expected, msg);
    }
}
```

The full codes are in the snippets in case I've forgotten to include something that's necessary.

```html
public class Triangle {

    private double sideA;
    private double sideB;
    private double sideC;
    
    public final static String POLYGONSHAPE = "Triangle";
    
    public final static double DEFAULT_SIDE = 1;
    
    //CONSTRUCTORS
    
    public Triangle()
    {
        this.sideA = DEFAULT_SIDE;
        this.sideB = DEFAULT_SIDE;
        this.sideC = DEFAULT_SIDE;
    }
    
    public Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)
    {
        if (isTriangle(sideA,sideB,sideC))
        {
            this.sideA = sideA;
            this.sideB = sideB;
            this.sideC = sideC;
        }
        else
        {
            sideA = DEFAULT_SIDE;
            sideB = DEFAULT_SIDE;
            sideC = DEFAULT_SIDE;
        }
    }
    
    public Triangle(double[] sides)
    {
        this();
        
        if (isTriangle(sides))
        {
            this.sideA = sides[0];
            this.sideB = sides[1];
            this.sideC = sides[2];
        }
        else 
        {
            this.sideA = DEFAULT_SIDE;
            this.sideB = DEFAULT_SIDE;
            this.sideC = DEFAULT_SIDE;
        }
    }
    
    public Triangle(Triangle triangle)
    {
        Triangle newTriangle = new Triangle();
        
        if (triangle != null)
        {
            if (isTriangle(triangle.getSideA(), triangle.getSideB(), triangle.getSideC()))
            {
                newTriangle.setSideA(triangle.getSideA());
                newTriangle.setSideB(triangle.getSideB());
                newTriangle.setSideC(triangle.getSideC());
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            newTriangle.setSideA(DEFAULT_SIDE);
            newTriangle.setSideB(DEFAULT_SIDE);
            newTriangle.setSideC(DEFAULT_SIDE); 
        }
    }
    
    //SIDE GETTERS
    
    public double getSideA()
    {
        return sideA;
    }
    
    public double getSideB()
    {
        return sideB;
    }
    
    public double getSideC()
    {
        return sideC;
    }
    
    public double[] getSides()
    {
        double[] sides = {sideA, sideB, sideC};
        
        return sides;   
    }
    
    //ANGLE GETTERS
    
    public double getAngleA()
    {
        double angleA = lawOfCosines(sideB, sideC, sideA);
        
        return angleA;      
    }
    
    public double getAngleB()
    {
        double angleB = lawOfCosines(sideC, sideA, sideB);
        
        return angleB;  
    }
    
    public double getAngleC()
    {
        double angleC = lawOfCosines(sideA, sideB, sideC);
        
        return angleC;      
    }
    
    public double[] getAngles()
    {
        return new double[] {getAngleA(), getAngleB(), getAngleC()};
    }
    
    //SIDE SETTERS
    
    public boolean setSideA(double sideA)
    {
        if (isTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC))
        {
            this.sideA = sideA;
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean setSideB(double sideB)
    {
        if (isTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC))
        {
            this.sideB = sideB;
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean setSideC(double sideC)
    {
        if (isTriangle(sideA, sideB, sideC))
        {
            this.sideC = sideC;
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean setSides(double[] sides)
    {
        if (isTriangle(sides))
        {
            this.sideA = sides[0];
            this.sideB = sides[1];
            this.sideC = sides[2];
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    //HELPER METHODS
    
    public static boolean isTriangle(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        //check if sides are positive
        if (a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0)
        {
            //check if they satisfy triangle inequality
            if ((a + b) > c && (a + c) > b && (b + c) > a)                                                  //(a + b) > c && (a + c) > b && (b + c) > a)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    public static boolean isTriangle(double[] sides)
    {
        
        if (sides == null || sides.length != 3 || sides[0] <= 0 || sides[1] <= 0 || sides[2] <= 0 || sides[0] + sides[1] <= sides[2] || sides[0] + sides[2] <= sides[1] || (sides[1] + sides[2]) <= sides[0])
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }

            }
    
    public static double lawOfCosines(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        double angle; 
        
        //find angle in radians
        angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((Math.pow(b, 2) + Math.pow(a, 2) - Math.pow(c, 2))/(2.0 * a * b)));
                
        return angle;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        String output = String.format("%s(%.4f, %.4f, %.4f)", POLYGONSHAPE, this.sideA, this.sideB, this.sideC);
        return output;
    }
    
    
    }
Here's a link to the given test code since it doesn't fit here: 
[https://lab2-triangletest.tiiny.site/][1]
```

When I run the test code, the failure trace tells me "Copy of null ==> expected: <1.0> but was: <0.0>". I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your constructor makes a new local `Triangle` and then throws it away, leaving the *actual* constructed `Triangle` half-initialized.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're creating a new triangle in the constructor and you're not assigning the values to the fields in the class. Therefore the actual triangle created from this constructor is a triangle with all sides 0 (default int value).

The code should look something like this:

```
public Triangle(Triangle triangle)
    {
        if (triangle != null)
        {
            //Is this check necessary? I'm assuming you cant create an invalid triangle.
            //So if it already exists, it's sides are valid.
            if (isTriangle(triangle.getSideA(), triangle.getSideB(), triangle.getSideC()))
            {
                this.setSideA(triangle.getSideA());
                this.setSideB(triangle.getSideB());
                this.setSideC(triangle.getSideC());
            }
        //If the check is necessary, what happens if sides are invalid? (else?)
        }
        else 
        {
            this.setSideA(DEFAULT_SIDE);
            this.setSideB(DEFAULT_SIDE);
            this.setSideC(DEFAULT_SIDE); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: The check was mostly because our professor stressed putting null checks into everything but looking at it again, the else statement probably isn't necessary since if the given values are null, they just won't be changed from the default. That being said, the test still comes back with the same error message?

Comment: Apparently it has to  do with your "SetSideA" / B / C methods. Assign the value directly to the field and it should work:                

this.sideA = triangle.getSideA();
this.sideB = triangle.getSideB();
this.sideC = triangle.getSideC();

Comment: PS. The null check is fine there. If you are given null as argument - then trying to get the sides of this triangle will produce a NullPointerException.